# Jquery - find value in array having 4 variables

Tags: jquery, arrays, search

I want to create packaging fee calculator.
I created few sliders. There are height, width, length and weight sliders. After user set all sliders I would like to retrieve the fee from array.
What is the best way to do it?

Link to table with data: https://services.amazon.co.uk/services/fulfilment-by-amazon/pricing.html

Link to my tool:http://tests.uk4u.pl/amazonProfitCalc/

What I did :

```
var slider_length_value = $(".slider-length").slider("value");
var slider_width_value = $(".slider-width").slider("value");
var slider_height_value = $(".slider-height").slider("value");

var slider_weight_value = $(".slider-weight").slider("value");   

var fullfilmentFee = Array({
        "packaging": "Small Envelope",
        "length": "20",
        "width": "15",
        "height": "1",
        "weight": "100",
        "fee": "1.07"
    },

    {
        "packaging": "Standard Envelope",
        "length": "33",
        "width": "23",
        "height": "2.5",
        "weight": "100",
        "fee": "1.19"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Envelope",
        "length": "33",
        "width": "23",
        "height": "2.5",
        "weight": "250",
        "fee": "1.31"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Envelope",
        "length": "33",
        "width": "23",
        "height": "2.5",
        "weight": "500",
        "fee": "1.51"
    },

    {
        "packaging": "Large Envelope",
        "length": "33",
        "width": "23",
        "height": "5",
        "weight": "1000",
        "fee": "1.70"
    },

    {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "250",
        "fee": "1.66"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "500",
        "fee": "1.72"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "1000",
        "fee": "1.77"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "1500",
        "fee": "2.19"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "2000",
        "fee": "2.41"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "3000",
        "fee": "3.30"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "4000",
        "fee": "3.40"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "5000",
        "fee": "3.40"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "6000",
        "fee": "3.45"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "7000",
        "fee": "3.45"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "8000",
        "fee": "3.53"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "9000",
        "fee": "3.53"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "10000",
        "fee": "3.53"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "11000",
        "fee": "3.53"
    }, {
        "packaging": "Standard Parcel",
        "length": "45",
        "width": "34",
        "height": "26",
        "weight": "12000",
        "fee": "3.54"
    }
);


var fee = $.map(fullfilmentFee, function(value, key) {
    if (value.length == "33") {
        //return value.fee;
        return value.fee;

    } else {
        $(".message").html("Error!!!");
    }
});
//console.log(price);
//output: $220
$(".message").html(fee);
```

Edit:

Again maybe. User prepars package and using sliders sets length width height and weight of this package. Next he  presses the submit button and get fulfilment fee which corresponds to those dims and weight. Very easy if all dims are exactly like in array but:

1. how to make conditionals where dims are between numbers in array like between

   fulfilment[0].length and fulfilment[1].length
2. If value of one or more variables(length or width or height or weight) is higher than normal range, I want to get fee which corresponds to this value.

Regards and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You have array with object so we can do simple for loop that will iterate on array single objects and we can get the fee amount from 'fee' key in every array object, like this:

```
function getCalculatedFee(fullfilmentFee){
        var fullAmount = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<=fullfilmentFee.length; i++){
           fullAmount += fullfilmentFee[i].fee;
        }

        return fullAmount;
    }
```

To get the single value try this:

```
fullfilmentFee[0].fee
```

According to your example you can make 4 functions which are getting fee for exact value (like length):

```
function getFeeByLength(slider_length_value){
    $.each(fullfilmentFee, function(value, key) {
        if (value.length == slider_length_value) {
            return value.fee;
        }
    });
}
```

and the same for the rest of user-chosen values. With this function-way you can call your function whenever you want - exactly where you need matching value.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but you did not understand what I want to achive.

Comment: You wrote 'After user set all sliders I would like to retrieve the fee from array. What is the best way to do it?' so in my opinion that is the best way to do it. Explain what you want instead of this, maybe i can help you

Comment: maybe you mean 'i should calculate fees on real time or on button submit?' so that question is more UX than programming. Anyway - please explain your problem

Comment: After user set weight, height, width and length I want to get fee which corresponds to those settings.

Comment: It can be after submit. I dont want to calculate - I want to get from array. Pozdrawiam

Comment: so you can get it by: fullfilmentFee[0].fee what is the problem to get it like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110388/discussion-between-alan-sobieraj-and-awariat).

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure what you are trying to do, but you can access the variable of the array item. You just have to do `fullfilmentFee[i].fee`. By doing `fullfilmentFee[i]` you get the `i` item in the array, and you can access  that item's variables by doing `.andTheVariable`, so it would be: `.packaging`, `.length`, `.width`, `.height`, `.weight` or `.fee`

Example:

`fullfilmentFee[0].fee` returns `1.07`

`fullfilmentFee[1].fee` returns `1.19`

Is that what you are looking for?

[EDIT]

I'm going to answer it here.
You have to check which `i` has length 19. To do this you check the whole array and for the one that has length 19, get its fee:

```
var feeForLength19; // where we are going to store the fee

// run the whole array
for(var i=0;i<=fullfilmentFee.length;i++){
    // for the variable that has length 19, we store his fee
    if(fullfilmentFee[i].length == 19){
        feeForLength19 = fullfilmentFee[i].fee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how display fee if user set slider lenght to 19 for example

Comment: Hello there, I edited the answer to show your example

Comment: there is no length =19 in array but it is 20. What i want to achive is get fee from line where length is 20 cos 20 is more than 19.

Comment: Another example - if user set length to 22 i want to get fee from fullfilmentFee[1].fee because 22 is between 20 and 33. Regards

Comment: With what I wrote it can be done, just use another condition in the if statement.